# Retrieve skipped white space In antlr4 parser from listener

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to construct an object from a parsed message.
I'm using Antlr4 and C++ 
My issue is that I need to skip white spaces during lexing/parsing but then I have to get them back when I construct my message object in the Listener.
Here's my grammar

```
grammar MessageTest;
WS: ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' )+ -> skip;

message: 
    messageInfo
    startOfMessage
    messageText+
| EOF;

messageInfo:
    senderName
    filingTime
    receiverName
;

senderName: WORD;

filingTime: DIGITS;

receiverName: WORD;

messageText: ( WORD | DIGITS | ALLOWED_SYMBOLS)+;

startOfMessage: START_OF_MESSAGE_SYMBOL ;

START_OF_MESSAGE_SYMBOL:':';

WORD: LETTER+;

DIGITS: DIGIT+;

LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';

ALLOWED_SYMBOLS:   '-'| '.' | ',' | '/' | '+' | '?';

fragment LETTER: [A-Z];

fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
```

So this grammar works well, my parsing tree is correct for the following message example: `JOHN0120JANE:HI HOW ARE YOU?` 
I get this parse tree:

```
message (
 messageInfo (
  senderName (
   "JOHN"
  )
  filingTime (
   "0120"
  )
  receiverName (
   "JANE"
  )
 )
 startOfMessage (
  ":"
 )
 messageText (
  "HI"
  "HOW"
  "ARE"
  "YOU"
  "?"
 )
)
```

The problem is when Im trying to retrieve the whole `messageText` as:
`HI HOW ARE YOU?` I instead get `HIHOWAREYOU?` from the `MessageTextContext`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add _space_ to  `ALLOWED_SYMBOLS`, or (probably more appropriate) change `messageText` into accepting a single token that in turn accepts all valid message characters.

Comment: adding space to ALLOWED_SYMBOLS results into space not part of the skipped characters for the other fields which means the messages "JOHN 0120JANE:HI HOW ARE YOU?" or "JOHN0120  JANE:HI HOW ARE YOU?" will have an unexpected space in them

Answer (score 2):

The `getText()` retrieval functions never consider skipped or hidden tokens. But it's easy to get the original text of your input (even just a range that corresponds to a specific parse rule), by using the indexes stored in the generated tokens. Parse rule contexts contain a start and an end node, so it's easy to go from the context to the original input like this:

```
std::string MySQLRecognizerCommon::sourceTextForContext(ParserRuleContext *ctx, bool keepQuotes) {
  return sourceTextForRange(ctx->start, ctx->stop, keepQuotes);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

std::string MySQLRecognizerCommon::sourceTextForRange(tree::ParseTree *start, tree::ParseTree *stop, bool keepQuotes) {
  Token *startToken = antlrcpp::is<tree::TerminalNode *>(start) ? dynamic_cast<tree::TerminalNode *>(start)->getSymbol()
                                                                : dynamic_cast<ParserRuleContext *>(start)->start;
  Token *stopToken = antlrcpp::is<tree::TerminalNode *>(stop) ? dynamic_cast<tree::TerminalNode *>(start)->getSymbol()
                                                              : dynamic_cast<ParserRuleContext *>(stop)->stop;
  return sourceTextForRange(startToken, stopToken, keepQuotes);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

std::string MySQLRecognizerCommon::sourceTextForRange(Token *start, Token *stop, bool keepQuotes) {
  CharStream *cs = start->getTokenSource()->getInputStream();
  size_t stopIndex = stop != nullptr ? stop->getStopIndex() : std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
  std::string result = cs->getText(misc::Interval(start->getStartIndex(), stopIndex));
  if (keepQuotes || result.size() < 2)
    return result;

  char quoteChar = result[0];
  if ((quoteChar == '"' || quoteChar == '`' || quoteChar == '\'') && quoteChar == result.back()) {
    if (quoteChar == '"' || quoteChar == '\'') {
      // Replace any double occurence of the quote char by a single one.
      replaceStringInplace(result, std::string(2, quoteChar), std::string(1, quoteChar));
    }

    return result.substr(1, result.size() - 2);
  }

  return result;
}
```

This code is tailored towards use with MySQL (e.g. wrt. quoting characters), but is easy to adapt for any other use case. The essential part is to use the tokens (e.g. taken from a parse rule context) and get the original input from the character input stream.

Code taken from the [MySQL Workbench code base](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/mysql/MySQLRecognizerCommon.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want [Lexical Modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md).

The idea of using them is simple: when your lexer encounters `START_OF_MESSAGE_SYMBOL`, it has to switch its context where only one token is possible, let's say `MESSAGE_TEXT` token.
Once this token has been determined, the lexer's mode switches back to its default mode.

To do this you should first split you grammar into two parts: lexer grammar and a parser grammar, since lexical modes are not allowed in a combined grammar. And then you can use 
`pushMode()` and `popMode()` commands.

Here's an example:

*MessageTestLexer.g4*

```
lexer grammar MessageTestLexer;

WS: ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' )+ -> skip;

START_OF_MESSAGE_SYMBOL:':' -> pushMode(MESSAGE_MODE); //pushing MESSAGE_MODE when START_OF_MESSAGE_SYMBOL is encountered

WORD: LETTER+;

DIGITS: DIGIT+;

LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';

ALLOWED_SYMBOLS:   '-'| '.' | ',' | '/' | '+' | '?';

fragment LETTER: [A-Z];

fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

mode MESSAGE_MODE; //tokens below are related to MESSAGE_MODE only

MESSAGE_TEXT: ~('\r'|'\n')*; //consuming any character until the end of the line. You can provide your own rule

END_OF_THE_LINE: ('\r'|'\n') -> popMode; //switching back to the default mode
```

*MessageTestParser.g4*

```
parser grammar MessageTestParser;

options {
    tokenVocab=MessageTestLexer; //declaring which lexer rules to use in this parser
}

message: 
    messageInfo
    startOfMessage
    MESSAGE_TEXT //use the token instead
| EOF;

messageInfo:
    senderName
    filingTime
    receiverName
;

senderName: WORD;

filingTime: DIGITS;

receiverName: WORD;

startOfMessage: START_OF_MESSAGE_SYMBOL;
```

P.S. did not test these grammars, but seems it should work.

Comment: I had something similar with modes but I was trying to avoid adding them since since grammar is fairly simple. I will try this thansk